# Angular: do not build undeclared components

Tags: angular

Due to huge refactorings in my app, I am having a lot of components that do not compile and I perfectly know why but the problem I am facing is however that the app cannot be built with the part that is already refactored.

All the components that yield an error are no longer declared in any module, nor referenced through any routing module, so why is the compiler complaining over it?

Is there a way to ignore these 'floating' components (for now)?

**EDIT**

To illustrate, I have for example this component called `GridComponent` that makes use of a third party library. It's HTML template is given below and the component won't compile since the `MtxGridModule` is not imported and therefore, the `<mtx-grid>`-tag is unknown.

**grid.component.html**

```
<div class="w-100 h-100">
  <mtx-grid
    [data]="dataSource"
    [columns]="columns"
  >
  </mtx-grid>
</div>
```

**grid.component.ts**

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-grid',
  templateUrl: './grid.component.html',
})
export class GridComponent {
...
}
```

To make this compile, I would have to include the third party module in the same module that declards the `GridComponent`. But my issue now is, I do not have any nodule that declares the `GridComponent`, I commented it out.

[image]

So the file `grid.component.ts` is just a floating file, but for some reason Angular still compiles it and I do not want that.

Comment: I don't believe that I do

Comment: It's not clear what you are asking. You can exclude things from being built by adding them to the `exclude` array in tsConfig.json, but I'm not sure if that's what you are asking.

Comment: No not exactly. It are way to much components for that. My question is when put very simply: why does Angular compiles loose components? I.e., a file ending in a `.ts` extension with a class annotated with @Component without being declared in a Module

Comment: angular does that indeed because angular compiler is written in that way. I would propose to delete the component and then, when you need it, revert the deletion from the git history